# How to add Autoscroll on insert in Tkinter Listbox?

Tags: python, listbox, scrollbar, tkinter

I'm using a listbox (with scrollbar) for logging:

```
self.listbox_log = Tkinter.Listbox(root, height = 5, width = 0,)
self.scrollbar_log = Tkinter.Scrollbar(root,)

self.listbox_log.configure(yscrollcommand = self.scrollbar_log.set)
self.scrollbar_log.configure(command = self.listbox_log.yview)
```

Now, when I do:

```
self.listbox_log.insert(END,str)
```

I want the inserted element to be selected. I've tried:

```
self.listbox_log.selection_anchor(END)
```

but that doesn't work... Please suggest a solution...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

AFAIK the ScrollBar widget doesn't have an auto-scroll feature, but it can be easily implemented by calling the `listBox`'s `yview()` method after you insert a new item. If you need the new item to be selected then you can do that manually too using the `listbox`'s `select_set` method.

```
from Tkinter import *

class AutoScrollListBox_demo:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master, width=500, height=400, bd=1)
        frame.pack()

        self.listbox_log = Listbox(frame, height=4)
        self.scrollbar_log = Scrollbar(frame) 

        self.scrollbar_log.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.listbox_log.pack(side=LEFT,fill=Y) 

        self.listbox_log.configure(yscrollcommand = self.scrollbar_log.set)
        self.scrollbar_log.configure(command = self.listbox_log.yview)

        b = Button(text="Add", command=self.onAdd)
        b.pack()

        #Just to show unique items in the list
        self.item_num = 0

    def onAdd(self):
        self.listbox_log.insert(END, "test %s" %(str(self.item_num)))       #Insert a new item at the end of the list

        self.listbox_log.select_clear(self.listbox_log.size() - 2)   #Clear the current selected item     
        self.listbox_log.select_set(END)                             #Select the new item
        self.listbox_log.yview(END)                                  #Set the scrollbar to the end of the listbox

        self.item_num += 1


root = Tk()
all = AutoScrollListBox_demo(root)
root.title('AutoScroll ListBox Demo')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can also use the listbox "see" command, though when viewing the end element the effect is the same.

Comment: thanks, I used 
self.listbox_log.insert(END,str)
size = len(self.listbox_log.get(-1, END))
self.listbox_log.yview_scroll(size,"units")
your way is much more elegent.

Answer (score 2):

try to do it in this way. (I have copied from another question: How to auto-scroll a gtk.scrolledwindow?) It works fine for me.

```
def on_TextOfLog_size_allocate(self, widget, event, data=None):
    adj = self.scrolled_window.get_vadjustment()
    adj.set_value( adj.upper - adj.page_size )
```

Comment: This won't work on a listbox because there is no `get_vadjustment` method, nor does the original question mention anything about a widget named `scrolled_window`. Are you sure you posted this answer to the right question?

Comment: I use pygtk but not tkint, sorry for the mistake.